# Limit of incomplete Beta function $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{B_\alpha(a+x,b)}{\alpha^x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I wish to prove that the following limit goes to zero:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{B_\alpha(a+x,b)}{\alpha^x} \to 0, \qquad \forall 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$$
where $B_\alpha(a+x,b) = \int_0^\alpha t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}t$ is the incomplete Beta function.

Using L'Hôpital's rule, yields the following:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{B_\alpha(a+x,b)}{\alpha^x} &=& \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^\alpha \log(t) t^{a+x-1} (1-t)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}t}{\log(\alpha) \alpha^x}
\end{eqnarray*}
which seemly does not lead to an answer in a finite number of steps.

Trying to use the monotone convergence theorem, the derivative can be simplified to: 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{B_\alpha(a+x,b)}{\alpha^x} = \frac{\int_0^\alpha \log\left(\frac{t}{\alpha}\right)t^{x+a-1}(1-t)^{b-a}\mathrm{d}t}{\alpha^x}$$
Which is negative since the $\log(\cdot)$ term is negative , but still I don't know how to show that it is bounded by zero at the limit.

Maybe  a transformation of variables should be applied?

Any help and ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  identity [eq. 8.17.7](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17), and thus,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{B_\alpha(a+x,b)}{\alpha^x}&=& \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\alpha^a {}_2 F_1 (a+x,1-b;1+a+x;\alpha)}{a+x},
\end{eqnarray*}
where ${}_2 F_1 (a+x,1-b;1+a+x;\alpha)$ is the hypergeometric function [eq. 15.2.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2).

Since the hypergeometric function converges for $\vert \alpha \vert < 1$, the enumerator converge, and the ratio goes to zero as $x\to \infty$.